# UIImageView doesn't center properly

Tags: ios, swift

I have an image view that I set up like this:

```
let buttonImageView: UIImageView = {
    let iv = UIImageView()
    iv.backgroundColor = .red
    iv.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
    iv.frame.size = CGSize(width: CGFloat(375 * (11 / 59)), height: CGFloat(375 * (11 / 59)))
    return iv
}()
```

Then, I add constraints:

```
/* center-top button */
// buttonImageView.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: buttonDiameter, height: buttonDiameter)
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonImageView, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: buttonDiameter))
addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonImageView, attribute: .width, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1, constant: buttonDiameter))
addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": buttonImageView]))
// addConstraintsWithFormat("H:[v0]", views: buttonImageView)
addConstraintsWithFormat("V:|-\(buttonSpacing)-[v0]", views: buttonImageView)
//addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))
```

[image]

Please ignore the "Hi!" square.  The red square below it, `buttonImageView`, should be at that vertical constraint, but centered horizontally.

Answer (score 1):

If you use constraints programmatically, you first need to activate them

```
blabla.constraint1.isActive = true;
```

Comment: haha, you'll have to use my variable names for me to understand.  I am very unfamiliar with Swift, and I can't find `.active`

Comment: `isActive` is what he's talking about

Answer (score 0):

Replace:

`addConstraints(NSLayoutConstraint.constraints(withVisualFormat: "H:[v0]", options: NSLayoutFormatOptions.alignAllCenterX, metrics: nil, views: ["v0": buttonImageView]))`

with:

`NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0.0).isActive = true`

Should do the trick.

Answer (score -1):

`addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: buttonImageView, attribute: .centerX, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: self, attribute: .centerX, multiplier: 1, constant: 0))`

Comment: Although this code might answer the question, you should add an explanation stating why/how it solves the problem.